# delete backwards until indentation

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, deletion, lines

In my config I have

```lisp
(bind-keys*
  ("C-<backspace>" . (lambda () (interactive) (kill-line 0))))
```

which deletes the entire line backwards until column position 0. I would like to only delete backwards until the indentation. How do I have to change this command then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lisp
(bind-keys* ("C-" . (lambda () (interactive) (back-to-indentation) (kill-line 1))))
```

Or maybe this is what you really want:

```lisp
(bind-keys* ("C-" . (lambda ()
                      (interactive)
                      (back-to-indentation)
                      (delete-region (point) (line-end-position)))))
```

There are several possibilities, depending on whether you want to remove whitespace, newline at the line end, etc., and whether you want to kill or just delete.

---

(I don't use `bind-key*`, so I'd use `global-set-key` or `define-key`.  And I'd define a *named* command and bind that.)

---

**UPDATE** after your comment that says what really you want is to delete only the text from indentation up to the original cursor position:

```lisp
(bind-keys* ("C-" . (lambda ()
                      (interactive)
                      (let ((opoint  (point)))
                        (back-to-indentation)
                        (delete-region (point) opoint)))))
```

I don't use `bind-keys*`.  But this is it with normal binding (and naming the command):

```lisp
(defun my-delete-back-to-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((opoint  (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (delete-region (point) opoint)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-<backspace>") 'my-delete-back-to-indent)
```

Comment: had that in use too found it too wordy imho, thanks though

Comment: Maybe I misspoke I want the stuff right of point to persist and not be deleted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you want the opposite of what you requested ("delete backwards until the indentation"), this removes the (whitespace) text from bol to the indentation: `(delete-region (line-beginning-position) (point))`. Is that really what you want, i.e., just to remove all of the indentation?

Comment: what I want is:

----some text and point is here x some more text

then if I hit C-<backspace> I want the following result

----x some more text

Comment: I added an example for that.

Comment: works like a charm, thank you a lot